# Firebase firestore not creating doc with recently created uid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase firestore db and I want to create a user then add a record to the db with the doc name as the uid.

This doesn't throw any errors in the console, but also does not create the record?

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        customerEmail.current.value, 
        customerPassword
    ).then(() => {
        console.log("UID!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('sessions')
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set(
            {...context.state}
        )
    })
```

Comment: Your code should work? Do you have any specific security rules? Do you see an error if you add a `catch()` block? Note that instead of doing `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`you can use the `UserCredential` returned by the [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) method.

Comment: It really should! I don't have any security rules yet - but I solved this by passing user.user.uid as the uid - which is weird!

Comment: "I solved this by passing user.user.uid as the uid" -> not sure to understand what you mean! is the first `user` the `UserCredential`?

Comment: Actually one should read in my first comment "Your code should work. Do you have..." without the question mark at the end of the first sentence! Based on your answer, by doing `user.user.uid` you are using the `UserCredential`. But normally, your previous code should also work, sincewith  the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method: "On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application." Weird indeed....

Comment: Any idea why it's not logging to the console when it saves successfully in the answer below?

Comment: Yes, because you should not pass a callback to the `set()` method, but use `then()`, since it returns a Promise. Look at this example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Comment: you may try to use onAuthStateChange, and get the uid from currentUser

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this works and the code above doesn't - and it still doesn't do anything when it saves successfully!

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        customerEmail.current.value, 
        customerPassword
    ).then(function(user) {
        console.log("UID!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", user, user.user.uid)
        firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('sessions')
        .doc(user.user.uid).set(
            {...context.state}, 
            function(error) {
                if (error) {
                  console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
                } else {
                  console.log("Data saved successfully.");
                }
              }
        )
    })
```